# Spring MVC test 3.2.2 fails "flash().attributeExists" assertion for some strange reason

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mockito, spring-mvc-test

I am testing the following **Spring MVC controller method**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/passwordReset", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
    public String resetPassword(@Validated({ ValidationGroups.PasswordReset.class }) @ModelAttribute PasswordInfo passwordInfo,   
            BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Locale locale) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("passwordInfo", passwordInfo);
            return "passwordReset";
        }
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", messageSource.getMessage("controller.preference.password_reset_ok", null, locale));
        Member member = preferenceService.findMemberByToken(passwordInfo.getToken());
        preferenceService.modifyPassword(member, passwordInfo.getNewPassword());
        signinService.signin(member);
        return "redirect:/preference/email";
    }
```

Here is my **test method**:

```
@Test
    public void resetPasswordShouldHaveNormalInteractions() throws Exception {
        Member member = new Member();
        when(preferenceService.findMemberByToken(eq("valid-token"))).thenReturn(member);
        mockMvc.perform(post("/preference/passwordReset")//
                .param("newPassword", "valid-password")//
                .param("token", "valid-token"))//
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/preference/email"))//
                .andExpect(flash().attributeExists("message"))//FAILS HERE
                .andExpect(flash().attributeCount(1));
        verify(preferenceService).modifyPassword(eq(member), eq("valid-password"));
        verify(signinService).signin(eq(member));
    }
```

**Even though the "message" flash attribute is added to the redirect attribute map, Spring MVC test does not seem to notice it and the line above `FAILS HERE` sytematically fails the test!**

You can see for yourself that **the `message` flash attribute is indeed in the FlashMap** (see `doPrint()`) below:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = POST
         Request URI = /preference/passwordReset
          Parameters = {newPassword=[valid-password], token=[valid-token]}
             Headers = {}

             Handler:
                Type = com.bignibou.controller.preference.PreferenceController
              Method = public java.lang.String com.bignibou.controller.preference.PreferenceController.resetPassword(com.bignibou.controller.preference.PasswordInfo,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes,java.util.Locale)

               Async:
   Was async started = false
        Async result = null

  Resolved Exception:
                Type = null

        ModelAndView:
           View name = redirect:/preference/email
                View = null
               Model = null

            FlashMap:
           Attribute = message
               value = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 302
       Error message = null
             Headers = {Location=[/preference/email]}
        Content type = null
                Body = 
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = /preference/email
             Cookies = []
```

*Can anyone please help? FYI I use Spring 3.2.2.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in the output of doPrint() FlashMap contains an attribute "message" with the value null.

```
.andExpect(flash().attributeExists("message"))
```

calls `attributeExists()` on an `FlashAttributeResultMatcher` but it only checks if there is an **not null** attribute:

```
/**
     * Assert the existence of the given flash attributes.
     */
    public <T> ResultMatcher attributeExists(final String... names) {
        return new ResultMatcher() {
            public void match(MvcResult result) throws Exception {
                for (String name : names) {
                    assertTrue("Flash attribute [" + name + "] does not exist", result.getFlashMap().get(name) != null);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Therefore the assertion fails.